# jquery background image rotating script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing this script to rotate a background Image every 3 seconds but it doesn't work at all and i'm stumped as to why not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var inc = 0;
        var bgImages = new Array();
        bgImages.push("Images/backgroundDog-small.jpg");
        bgImages.push("Images/backgroundDog1-small.jpg");
        bgImages.push("Images/backgroundDog2-small.jpg");
        bgImages.push("Images/backgroundDog3-small.jpg");

        setInterval(change, 3000);

        function change() {
            //if we're not at the end of the array
            if (inc < (bgImages.length)) {
                var image = bgImages[inc];
                $('body').css('backgroundImage', image);
                console.log(image);
                inc++;


            //reset the counter inc and go through the array again
            } else {
                inc = 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What happens? Are the image paths correct?

Comment: The background is white. Yes the image paths are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `background-image` attribute in CSS doesn't expect just the image URL; you need to write it like you actually would in a stylesheet: `url("example.png")`

```
$('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url("'+image+'")');
```